# React UseEffect function triggering in empty array change

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-router, next.js

The react application that I'm working on triggers the `userEffect` function if the prop value changes from an empty array to another empty array.

I'm getting query params from the page and passing them down in a component that re-renders if any of the query param array changes. But the issue is that the `useEffect` function triggers and re-renders the component even if the query param array changed from `[]` to `[]`.

I know that `[] !== []`, maybe that's what causing the issue. But is there a way that that the application can prevent triggering the useEffect function in the first place?

Heres a codesandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-greider-qgjgs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do. When exactly do you want the `useEffect` to run?

Comment: @jered , Just don't want to  trigger it if the prop changes from `[]` to `[]`

Comment: why not just use if-else inside useEffect? It will still trigger the function but the function can still decide what to do

Comment: @MuhammedB.Aydemir, maybe I could use an if statement to check for length.  what happens if the query param changes from `['some-data'] to `[]`. How do you handle that?

Comment: Is it an issue (performance) if the component rerenders for this edge-case? What is the concern?

Comment: @ProttayRudra I see, you will have to keep a reference to your previous state/prop to cover this case

Comment: @DrewReese, yes it is. The `useEffect` function calls an external paid api

Comment: Ah, then I agree with @MuhammedB.Aydemir, implement a [usePrevious](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state) hook and for this edge case test if going from a populated array to an empty one.

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning a new reference to the test hence it is triggering an update.

you should reassign the same array and to manipulation in it.

```
   const handleClick = () => {
   const arr = test
    setTest(arr);
  };
```

Comment: that might work in this specific scenario. But what should I do if the array is from query param?

Comment: it should also work there. As query param is going to change your array. It will be handle by useEffect. And in useEffect it will trigger automatically when it will get new data.

Comment: I meant the arrray is coming straight from the query param. I'm not doing anything with that array, just checking if the array different

Comment: can you provide your approach example where I can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create your own custom hook that checks for deep equality on each of the dependency array items or use one like [use-deep-compare-effect](https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, [you can also use `React.memo` as a way to do a comparison check between previous props and new props](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo). If your props is somewhat complicated, you can probably add Lodash on top of it too.

Comment: doesn't work. Heres a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-currying-fkbh1?file=/src/Test.js

Comment: Are you talking about props on `<Test />`? You are not passing anything on that component but that's not a big deal on the issue that you're having. Your `setTest` will rerender the App component, which subsequently rerenders its child component.